# jQuery select matching text within element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a way to pass an element id and a string to a function which selects any occurrences of that string in the element text, which is not already wrapped in a sub element.

I have an existing event handler which performs some actions, including wrapping the text in an element, when a user highlights a section of text. However some strings can be matched automatically without needing to be selected by a user, which is what I am trying to accomplish here. A different event will sometimes produce an element id and a string, and all instances of the string in the element text which are not all ready tagged, should be passed to the event handler as if a user had selected them.

Example:

```
var selectionString = 'word';
<p id="1">select this word, but not this <span>word</span>, but yes to this word.</p>

// My approach so far which may not be on the right track.
function selectStringInElement(selectionString, elementId){
    var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var selections = el.innerHTML.split(/<.+>/);
    for(var i=0; i < selections.length; i++){
        // if the selection contains the selectionString, find its range, select it, and pass to existing handler.
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say "select", do you mean return as a string (or possibly an array)? Or highlight text?

Comment: I think rurp might mean to wrap matched text in an element.

Comment: @Mark That's a good question and I'm not sure what the best way is. I have an existing ```on('mouseup'``` handler that operates on selected text and I need to apply the same logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML nodes have children accessible by node.childNodes, and you can tell if a child node is text or an element by node.nodeType.

This example takes the search string and the element id to search, filters it so only the text nodes are left, and then does a replace to generate a new html string.  You can't just jam a HTML string into a text node, so I used a temporary div to parse the html string into nodes, which are then injected into the element's parent before removing the source text node itself.

```js
function selectStringInElement(selectionString, elementId, className) {
  $("#" + elementId).contents()
  .filter(function(i, el){ 
    // only process text nodes
    return el.nodeType == 3 
  }).each(function(i, el){
    // create a div to process our html string with new tags
    var fake = document.createElement('div');

    fake.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace(
      new RegExp(selectionString,'g'),
      "<span class='" + className + "'>" + selectionString + "</span>"
    );

    // take all the nodes in our div and append them to the actual element's parent
    $(fake.childNodes).each(function(i, child) {
      el.parentNode.insertBefore(child, el);
    });

    // we've now duplicated our actual element with a number of new elements, we don't need to keep the original
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  });
}
selectStringInElement('chowder','test', 'red');
selectStringInElement('ukulele','test', 'blue');
```

```css
.red {
  color: #f00;
}
.blue {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>
The bottle of shampoo just returned from a safari, that he left the tea and the church bazaar. She was a grand ran all around the veranda, laughing like, so helping their ranch on the cook make the church bazaar. She was playing a ukulele, which the admiral did not like, so he looked through his collection of the kindergarten cried, "At last! Hurrah!" -- and by accident spilled the ketchup all over the taffy apples! This so amused another chores at the bottle had just where he had found the taffy apples! This so amused another guest, who usually wore a gingham dress and moccasins when visiting their ranch on the cook make the church bazaar. She was no helping the chowder and kayak he had seen.

Someone was playing a ukulele, which the ketchup all over the goulash for lunch. the label.

The admiral heard them talking in the label.

The admiral heard them talking in the bank and firing his pistol out of his sack and ran all around the chowder and the goulash for lunch. the Nebraska prairie, had just returned from her chores at imaginary zombies. It was a grand party.d through his collection of shampoo just returned from a safari, that he pulled the ketchup all over the church bazaar. She was no helping the church bazaar. She was no helping the admiral hated to a pretty mazurka by Chopin. Then he looked through his sack and ran all around the kitchen.

Someone was a grand party.ard them talking in the admiral did not like a maniac and firing his pistol out of his so amused another guest, who usually wore a gingham dress and listened to a pretty mazurka by Chopin. The bottle had seen.

Someone was playing a ukulele, which the admiral heard them talking in the label.

The admiral's wife, who usually wore a gingham dress and moccasins when visiting their ranch on the label.

When everyone sat down to eat, the pulled a toy pistol out of his sack and ran all around through his collection of pictures -- next to the tea and listened to snoop, so he turned on the radio and the cook make the church bazaar. She was playing a ukulele, which the admiral did not like, so amused another guest, who had just returned on the Nebraska prairie, had just returned on the Nebraska prairie, had a picture of shampoo just returned from a safari, that he pulled the radio and listened from her chowder and the label.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the code and explanation are very clear. I can replace the span with the project specific logic and this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is JQuery implementation:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6687Ljab/)

```
     selectStringInElement('word','1');


function selectStringInElement(selectionString, elementId)
{

    var $el =  $("#"+elementId);

    $el.contents()
    .filter(function(){ 
            return this.nodeType === 3 // Only text nodes
     })
    .each(function(){
        this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(new RegExp(selectionString,'g'),"<span class='highlight'>"+selectionString+"</span>");
     });

      // Decoding lt/gt
      var html = $("<textarea/>").html($("#1").html()).val() 

      // Replacing original content
      $el.html(html);

     // Attaching onMouseOver events
      console.log($el.find("span.highlight"));
      $el.find("span.highlight").on("mouseover",function(){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
}
```

Result: "word" is surrounded with span tag, and onMouseOver event attached to  that tags.

HTML resulting code:

```
<p id="1">select this <span class="highlight">word</span>, but not this <span>word</span>, but yes to this <span class="highlight">word</span>.</p>
```